# jQuery - How come the spinner is not showing up in safari

Tags: jquery, html

I have this jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#credit_btn, #checkout_btn').click(function(){
    $("#content_container .notice, #content_container .error").remove();
    $('#loading').show();
  });
});
```

The HTML

```
<div id="loading" style="display: none;">
  <img alt="spinner" border="0" src="/assets/spinner.gif">
</div>
<input class="bigbutton" data-disable-with="One Moment, Processing..." id="checkout_btn" name="commit" type="submit" value="Next Step: Checkout">
```

why is the spinning not showing up it shows up when i do

```
  $j('#credit_btn, #checkout_btn').click(function(){
    $j("#content_container .notice, #content_container .error").remove();
    $j('#loading').show();
    return false;
  });
```

what is happening here and is there anything I can do? Thanks in advance

UPDATE

I tested this jquery as well

```
  $('#credit_btn, #checkout_btn').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#content_container .notice, #content_container .error").remove();
    $('#loading').show();
    $(this).closest("form").submit();
  });
```

the spinner doesnt come up again but it shows up when i remove the line `$(this).closest("form").submit();` ...I am confused...why does the form submit have anything to do why the loader

Comment: Do you get any errors? Does your loading `div` show up, or is the image just not visible?

Comment: I am not seeing any errors in safari...i will update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your form gets submitted, and so the page is reloaded. (*you are seeing the page that the form direct you to*)

This is the normal browser behavior. You might want to try submitting your form with AJAX, if you need to remain on the current page..

Comment: Before the page submits the spinner should show up for a second before the page does to the new page. This works that way in chrome but not safari

Comment: Images that are not displayed (*when inside `display:none` blocks*) are not loaded until it is needed to be displayed, and this might be the cause. You could try submitting the form a second later with `setTimeout()`